Swift Bar Mark Chart Overflowing View With Custom Axis Range
When making a swift Chart view and displaying data with the bar mark item stlye, and formatting the y axis scale to be in line with the range of the data, the bar marks on the chart overflow the view. They appear to be scaled up to match the new axis scale, but go all the way to where the "0" would be.

Where weights is an array of Weight swift data model objects with date and measurement properties.
    Chart(weights) { weight in
                            BarMark(x: .value("Date", weight.date, unit: .day),
                                     y: .value("Weight", weight.measurement))
                        }
                        .chartYScale(domain: WeightRange())
                        .chartXScale(domain: [Date().addingTimeInterval(-3600*25*7*4),Date()])
                        .padding(.leading, 40)
                        .padding(.trailing, 40)
                        .padding(.top, 10)
                        .padding(.bottom, 20)
                        .frame(height: 200)

I've tried setting a frame on the view, the bar marks still overflow it. If I go back to the default y axis scale then the issue goes away.
Minimum Working Example
import SwiftUI

@main
struct MyApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            Main()
        }
    }
}

import SwiftUI
import Charts

func WeightRange() -> [Double] {
    var maxWeight = 0.0
    var minWeight = 1000.0
    
    for weight in weights {
        if weight.measurement > maxWeight { maxWeight = weight.measurement }
        if weight.measurement < minWeight { minWeight = weight.measurement }
    }
    
    return [minWeight - 5, maxWeight + 5]
}

struct Weight: Identifiable {
    var id: UUID = UUID()
    
    var measurement: Double
    var date: Date
    
}

var weights = [Weight(measurement: 260.0, date: Date()), Weight(measurement: 262.0, date: Date().addingTimeInterval(-3600*24))]

struct Main: View {
    var body: some View {
        Chart(weights) { weight in
            BarMark(x: .value("Date", weight.date, unit: .day),
                    y: .value("Weight", weight.measurement))
        }
        .chartYScale(domain: WeightRange())
        .chartXScale(domain: [Date().addingTimeInterval(-3600*25*7*4),Date()])
        .padding(.leading, 40)
        .padding(.trailing, 40)
        .padding(.top, 10)
        .padding(.bottom, 20)
        .frame(height: 200)
    }
}


Please show a [mcve] - something I can copy and paste into a new project, and reproduce the issue.

I've added a minimal reproducible example that demonstrates the issue

Add clipped() to Chart{}. This quirk might be fixed in Charts in the future.
Using your example:
    struct Main: View {
        var body: some View {
            Chart(weights) { weight in
                BarMark(x: .value("Date", weight.date, unit: .day),
                                y: .value("Weight", weight.measurement))
            }
            .clipped()  // Add this
            .chartYScale(domain: WeightRange())
            .chartXScale(domain: [Date().addingTimeInterval(-3600*25*7*4),Date()])
            .padding(.leading, 40)
            .padding(.trailing, 40)
            .padding(.top, 10)
            .padding(.bottom, 20)
            .frame(height: 200)
        }
    }

The result:

